# Simple proof for Fourier transformation (DFT)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

The question is in the image below: 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4ghq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n \exp(-2 \pi i kn /N)$$

Notice that $\exp(0) = 1$, by setting $k=0$ in the above equation,

\begin{align}y_0 &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n \exp(-2 \pi i 0n /N)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n \exp(0)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n \end{align}

Comment: You think you can add some written explanation for this? I would get help me internalize the idea more. Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform reading on discrete fourier transform.

Comment: 2 remarks 1) "it is the sum" only is the normalization coefficient is 1, but, rather often, it is not 1, but, for example $1/\sqrt{N}$  2) This fact shouldn't come as a surprise: this result is the discrete analog of coefficient $a_0$ which is the sum (up to a certain coefficient) of $f(t)$ (here "sum" in the sense of "integral of $f$ on $[0,2\pi]$). Do you see the analogy